# Using the $pull operator to remove an object via a nested field from an array in DocumentDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I have one entry in my `Data` collection and is as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "key1": {
                "name": "test"
            }
        },
        {
            "key1": {
                "name": "test2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to remove the object where `key1.name: 'test2'` from the `data` array.

I have tried the following:

```
db.Data.updateOne({}, { $pull: { 'data': { 'key1.name': 'test2' } } })
```

This works fine in a container instance of mongodb (latest).

But in a DocumentDB with engine version 5.0, it does not work and returns `MongoServerError: Dotted field name is not valid for storage`.

Is there any way for me to use the $pull operator in a DocumentDB where I'm targeting an object via a nested field?